# Selected option does not show in dropdown menu

Tags: php

I have created function, which retrieve the data from database and put it into dropdown menu. That step works fine.

Here I get dropdown menu with all needed values.

```
function termopaneli() {
   $link = new mysqli("localhost", "xxx", "xxxx", "xxx");
   $link->set_charset("utf8");
   $sql=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM termopaneli order by PaneliId asc");
   echo '<option value="">Izaberi panel</option>';
   while($record=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
      echo '<option value= "' .$record['PaneliId']. '">' . $record['PaneliNaziv'] . ' </option>';
}
}
```

Later on when I want to see what is chosen inside dropdown, it does not print. I am using this form to edit, so selected value is important. 
First I get values from database. Everything works except for printing selected value in dropdown.

First I get $panel value and when I echo $panel, I get value I should. But it does not show up as selected option.

```
<label>Panel</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="panel" value="<?php echo $panel; selected" ?>">
    <option value=<?php echo $panel?> selected>
      <?php termopaneli()?>
    </option>
  </select>
```

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `</option>` should come before your PHP function call.

Also, check the value in `<select>` is correct?

```
<label>Panel</label>
<select class="form-control" name="panel" value="<?php echo $panel; ?>">
   <option value=<?php echo $panel?> selected> SELECTED_OPTION </option>
   <?php termopaneli()?>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose at time of edit u have selected value like $select=5

```html
<label>Panel</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="panel" value="<?php echo $panel; selected" ?>">
    <option value=<?php echo $panel?> selected>
      <?php termopaneli($select)?>
    </option>
  </select>

function termopaneli($select) {
   $link = new mysqli("localhost", "xxx", "xxxx", "xxx");
   $link->set_charset("utf8");
   $sql=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM termopaneli order by PaneliId asc");
   echo '<option value="">Izaberi panel</option>';
   while($record=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
      echo '<option value= "' .$record['PaneliId']. '"; if($record['PaneliID']==$select){echo 'selected=selected'}>' . $record['PaneliNaziv'] . ' </option>';
}
}
```